# How to compile for S60 2nd Edition in Carbide 2.3

Tags: symbian, carbide

Im using carbide 2.3 to develop an application for 3rd and 5th editions of S60. Now my customer also wants to make the application compatible for 2nd edtion.

I have downloaded and installed CW 2nd edition S60 SDK. But carbide 2.3 doesnt provide any template to create application for 2nd edition. How do i proceed???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the 2nd edition SDK. But I guess you could compile it manually in your console/terminal. There should be enough tutorials how to do this on the web. If that works, you also should be able to configure your own run configuration in Eclipse (Carbide C++ IDE).